# Loading UIView from xib, crashes when trying to access IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, nib

I have a xib-file with a small `UIView` on it, which in turn contains some labels. Now, I'm trying to load that `UIView` into an existing `UIViewController`, and change one of the label-texts. The reason I want to do it this way, is that the `UIView` will be reused with different label-texts so I figured making a custom class and loading it from a xib would be the best way to go.

I have tried several ways of loading it and I've successfully displayed it on my viewcontroller. The problem is, once I try to actually link an `IBOutlet` in Interface Builder, and access it, my app crashes.

I have created a custom `UIView` class, which looks like this:

**CoverPanel.h**

```
@interface CoverPanel : UIView {

    IBOutlet UILabel *headline;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *headline;

@end
```

**CoverPanel.m**

```
@implementation CoverPanel

@synthesize headline;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Initialization code.
        //
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CoverPanel" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In the `CoverPanel.xib`, I have linked the `UILabel` to the headline outlet.
In my viewcontroller, here's how I create the `CoverPanel` instance, and this is where it crashes:

```
CoverPanel *panelView = [[CoverPanel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,100)];
```

So far, so good. It displays the `UIView` exactly as it's layed out in the .xib.
But as soon as I try to change the `headline.text` like so:

```
panelView.headline.text = @"Test";
```

it crashes with this error:
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView headline]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c22b00'**

It might be something tiny I'm overlooking, but it has been driving me insane for hours and hours so far. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You reassigned your custom view's class to the view that lived in your xib. You don't need to do that because then what you got back was the view from the xib and you've just leaked your CoverPanel. So, simply replace your initializer:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // No need to re-assign self here... owner:self is all you need to get
        // your outlet wired up...
        UIView* xibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CoverPanel" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        // now add the view to ourselves...
        [xibView setFrame:[self bounds]];
        [self addSubview:xibView]; // we automatically retain this with -addSubview:
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Oh of course, that makes perfect sense. It works now, thanks!