# Cannot assign to self in a method - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

In Xcode 6.1 and with the blog post about [Failable Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) on the Swift Blog, Apple has assigned to self in a failable initializer.

The Int (init(fromString:)) example on the blog post compiles fine when copied into my project with an assignment to self, but trying this with a custom class in my own code results in the usual error "Cannot assign to 'self' in a method".

```
extension Contact {
    public convenience init?(context: NSManagedObjectContext = DataStore.managedObjectContext) {
        if let userId = User.loggedInUserId(context) {
            let contact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Contact

            self = contact
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

(Contact is a subclass of NSManagedObject)

Is there anything I am missing with failable initializers?

Comment: Awesome answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27647411/3411787

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Assigning to `self`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_362) is for value types only, `struct` and `enum`.

In your case you should do like this:

```
public convenience init?(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context);
    self.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    if  User.loggedInUserId(context)  == nil {
        context.deleteObject(self)
        return nil
    }
}
```

You must call `self.init(..)` unconditionally, because, it's a rule for `convenience` initializer.
If the condition is `false`, `deleteObject(self)` and `return nil`. Hmm... I think you should not use
failable initializers for this.

Comment: Wouldn't have to delete except it seems you have to call self.init(entity before returning nil. Can't do the checks before calling the designated initialiser.

Answer (score 0):

A convenience initializer must call a designated initializer from the same class. Instead of assigning to `self`, can you create a designated initializer that takes and copies a `Contact` instance?