# Custom UILabel not loading from xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I have a `CustomLabel` view which is a sub-class of `UILabel` it self.

Is there any possibility to set properties from Xcode Interface builder for this custom view. I have tried different things specified in this link:

[Reuse a uiview xib in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335089/reuse-a-uiview-xib-in-storyboard/30335090#30335090)

But nothing is working for me. Will this kind of thing work ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to style the view from xib

Comment: You can use IB_DESIGNABLES. Please provide more info on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i think its not possible. if you want like this, first we need to add UILabel in interface builder and take outlet connection then we can set properties.

example: self.myLabel.text="hi welcome"