# UIView: Loading from custom XIB causing a crash

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, crash, xib

Hello StackOverflow.

- I am trying to setup a `UIView` such that it loads itself from `XIB`
  file in Xcode.

To do this, I went through the following initial steps:

1. Created empty `UIView` subclass.
2. Added a blank `XIB` file.

Then, I added all the subviews I wanted into the `XIB` file, and made corresponding `IBOutlet Properties` inside the `UIView` Subclass.

I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/xP7YvdlnHfA) to show me how to properly connect the outlets and set the files owner. The video instructs me to do the following things:

- Do not set the UIView class to your subclass in `XIB`. [Time link](https://youtu.be/xP7YvdlnHfA?t=5m50s)
- Set the `File's Owner` to your `UIView` subclass in `XIB`:[Time Link](https://youtu.be/xP7YvdlnHfA?t=5m52s)
- Insert a IBOutlet into your UIView class of type UIView so your XIB file can load into that.[Time link](https://youtu.be/xP7YvdlnHfA?t=6m15s)
- Override `initWithCoder` [like (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4t1r.jpg) if you intend to initialize the custom `UIView` within another `XIB` file.
- Override `initWithFrame` [like (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Qhr.jpg) if you intend to initialize the custom `UIView` *programatically* within another class file.

Cool, I have done all of these things, and am choosing to initialize my `UIView` programatically.

See my `UIView` subclass **implementation file**:

```
#import "CXHostsTableViewCellContentView.h"

@implementation CXHostsTableViewCellContentView



#pragma mark Custom Initializers

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CXHostsTableViewCellContentView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self setBounds:self.view.bounds];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CXHostsTableViewCellContentView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And of course, my **header file**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CXStyleView.h"

@interface CXHostsTableViewCellContentView : UIView

#pragma mark UIView Properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;

@property (nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UIView *standardView;

@end
```

I also have an [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4O1b.png) of the XIB file's owner and [another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R78FC.png) of the `IBOutlet` link from the base `UIView` to the outlet on file's owner.

Right, so everything's looking pretty good, should be no problem running this right?

Nope, whenever I initialize this subview and present it, I get a crash:

```
CXHostsTableViewCellContentView *scrollContentView = [[CXHostsTableViewCellContentView alloc]init];
```

[image: Screenshot of exception]

I've really got no idea how to solve this, as I'm sure I'm following all of these steps right. I've googled and come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039209/loading-uiview-from-xib-crashes-when-trying-to-access-iboutlet) which has the same symptoms, but the answer has identical code to what I'm using, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314818/custom-uiview-loaded-from-xib) with a contradictory reply.

I'm not sure what to do at this point, or what is causing the crash. I know that if I have NO outlets linked at all, it works. But then again, nothing displays either.

Comment: You probably need to continue the execution after the crash and give us what you see in the console (stack trace, exception details, etc.)

Comment: @mohamede1945 There is nothing but some scant information concerning memory addresses. No telling names, or figures stand out at all.

Comment: Hi @Owatch, did you fix this? I'm currently experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that You will face Problem When You Allocate Memory to Your  scrollContentView object.
so,Try To allocate Memory With Frame.

i.e
**Write this in .m file**

```
- (void)myAllocation {
              
  //do your stuff
            
}
        
-  (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect {
           
   self = [super initWithFrame:aRect];
        
   if (self) {
      [self myAllocation];
   }
        
   return self;
        
}
        
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
           
   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   if (self) {
      [self myAllocation];
   }
        
   return self;
        
}
```

...

```
CXHostsTableViewCellContentView *scrollContentView = [[CXHostsTableViewCellContentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 0, 20)];
```

Comment: I don't understand your response, what is myAllocation? How does this solve my problem?

Comment: Hello Owatch, Can you send me sample/demo project for this? So, that I can help you.

Comment: I'll post it here in 2 hours.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwYE5uc9NjE-dlNFTGpSUU5WcGM/view Here is the link, accidentally gave it to someone else who commented earlier. My bad. To simulate the crash, simply go open up the App and try accessing the "Hosts" screen off the menu.